# Micronaut Test Resources: How to extend AbstractTestContainersProvider class

Tags: java, gradle, micronaut, micronaut-test

Micronaut documentation says:

> For test resources which make use of Testcontainers, you may extend
> the base AbstractTestContainersProvider class.

My question is: how to add this class properly to the classpath of the test resources sourceset (I am using Gradle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the following dependencies to your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    testResourcesImplementation platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:3.6.1")
    testResourcesImplementation "io.micronaut.testresources:micronaut-test-resources-testcontainers"
}
```

(note that I'm importing the Micronaut BOM so that you don't have to specify the test resources version, but you could use it directly)